# Do OpenZeppelin Clones support ancestor contracts?

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, chainlink, proxy-contracts, clone

I would like to know whether clones made using the OpenZeppelin Clones Library supports functions of inherited contracts (eg: using override functions, etc). I would like my cloned contract to make use of ChainLink VRF and ChainLink Keepers, and would like to know whether to use clones or proxies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike contracts, Solidity libraries are not inherited from and instead rely on using the `for` syntax (e.g. `using Counters for Counters.Counter`). Hence, clones made using the OpenZeppelin Clones Library do not support functions of inherited contracts (eg: using override functions, etc).

See: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/extending-contracts

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the functions in the other contracts, you need to use the FOR keyword.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't, like the answer above you'd have to use the `using _ for _` in your contract.